# Immutable Objects in multi threaded application - how does it work?

Tags: java, multithreading, object, concurrency, immutability

I have this code will work in multithreaded application.
I know that immutable object is thread safe because its state cannot be changed. And if we have volatile reference, if is changed with e.g. 
MyImmutableObject state = MyImmutableObject.newInstance(oldState, newArgs); i.e. if a thread wants to update the state it must create new immutable object initializing it with the old state and some new state arguments) and this will be visible to all other threads.
But the question is, if a thread2 starts long operation with the state, in the middle of which thread1 updates the state with new instance, what will happen? Thread2 will use reference to the old object state i.e. it will use inconsistent state? Or thread2 will see the change made by thread1 because the reference to state is volatile, and in this case thread1 can use in the first part of its long operation the old state and in the second part the new state, which is incorrect?

```
State state = cache.get(); //t1 
Result result1 = DoSomethingWithState(state); //t1 
        State state = cache.get(); //t2
    ->longOperation1(state); //t1
        Result result2 = DoSomethingWithState(state); //t2
             ->longOperation1(state); //t2
   ->longOperation2(state);//t1
cache.update(result1); //t1 
             ->longOperation2(state);//t2
        cache.update(result2);//t2

Result DoSomethingWithState(State state) {
    longOperation1(state);
    //Imaging Thread1 finish here and update state, when Thread2 is going to execute next method
    longOperation2(state);
return result;
}

class cache {
     private volatile State state = State.newInstance(null, null);

    update(result) {
        this.state = State.newInstance(result.getState, result.getNewFactors);

    get(){
       return state;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Please don't cross post http://forums.oracle.com/forums/messageview.jspa?messageID=9751573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the reference is `volatile`, isn't it making visible the new object state … to the other threads?

No. While a write to a `volatile` field [happens-before](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.5) every subsequent read of that field,  the other thread must re-read that field to get the new value.

Comment: How this can be accomplished?

Comment: I don't understand the problem well enough to propose a correct solution. It's not clear to me how the long operations are related or why there are two threads or what it means to `update()` an immutable object.

Comment: Let say i have a process executors, which must use shared state and eventually modify it after finish. Every process is started in new thread, the process logic is stateless, the state is cached in in-memory cache.
Every process is doing some work based on the state. According the state the process logic can resolve different cases and the result of these cases is the new update of the state. After finishing the process logic i construct new immutable object from the current state and the result.

Comment: Then you'll have to synchronize access to the shared state. See [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/).

Comment: So in this case i can run 2 threads to execute the process logic, they both get the latest immutable state, but the one who finish last will simply override the change of the other. 
Both threads will never see the change of the other, even the reference is volatile, which basicly means that the access to the volatile private property is lightweight synchronization. Any copied reference will not see changes to the private property.

Comment: Some other question related to this topic. What about the http session?
Many people here say that the objects stored in the http session must be immutable. I think this is the same case and it is wrong.
Also some say better to be atomic reference, which may be ok if i use compareAndSet, but if it returns false i must do a failover of my logic and the better solution is to synchronize on session object.

Comment: What http session? Please edit your question to reflect your actual problem.

Comment: i mean this is the same concept problem -> one http session(state), many requests(threads) read/modify it.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is not thread safe, despite the fact that you are using immutable objects. `thread2` continues to act on the object it originally obtained a reference to, even if `thread1` assigns a new value of `state` concurrently. In java, object references are passed *by value*. So when the `state` argument to `DoSomethingWithState()` or `longOperation1()` gets passed, the method sees only the object reference that was passed, not the changing values later. If you want this kind of code to be thread safe, you need to synchronize all methods that act on the singleton `state` object.

Comment: But the reference is volatile, is'n it making visible the new object state (at which the volatile reference is pointing) to the other threads.

Comment: @dimitar: In java, object references are passed _by value_. This means that `DoSomethingWithState()` gets a copy of the object reference. If you change the reference in another scope after that, `DoSomethingWithState()` isn't affected.

Comment: Yes i know that, it thread1 changes the cache reference to point to ne object value, the copy of the reference in DoSomethingWithState will still point to the old object value. So the volatile reference is not always 100% visible to all threads, only for threads which re-read the state.

Comment: So what is the best way to keep thread safe my state, and not to break logic, because i don't want different threads to work with different sate.